# Adb install fails, but takes space anyways

Tags: android, adb

So, the thing is that if I install an apk using adb and installation is aborted midway due to a random reason - part of the transferred data stays in the device system storage (somewhere), and eventually it can fill up all the available storage (which is happened to one of my devices I use for testing).

I want to know where exactly android (4.1.2 in my case) can store unfinished apks, and is there a way to delete them without rooting the device?

Comment: check `/data/local/tmp`

Comment: @AlexP. you are my savior )). (there was like 2GBs of trash)